# file not getting created after redirection and "cp: cannot stat" error

Tags: bash, scripting

In the bash script below, I check whether a file exists or not and then if it doesn't, I create it and write a simple snippet to it. It worked once(I don't know why), but I guess I have changed something and it's no more working, I can't find where's my mistake:

```
#...

template_file="~/mytest_template.c";

if [[ -z $template_file ]]; then
   echo -e "#include <stdio.h>\n#include <stdlib.h>\n\n\nint main(int argc, char**argv){\n\n\t\n\nreturn 0;\n}" > ~/mytest_template.c;
fi

#sleep 0.5; ---> I tried this too.

cp ~/mytest_template.c mytest.c;
```

The error I get is this:
`cp: cannot stat '/home/username/mytest_template.c': No such file or directory`

Thanks.

Comment: @John1024 I did it now. still doesn't work. it gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [[ -z $template_file ]]; then
```

The `-z` operator tests if a string is empty. Here, the value of `template_file` isn't empty, since you just assigned to it. Hence the command inside the `if` doesn't run.

If the file didn't exist before the script was run, it won't exist at the time of the `cp` either.

I'm not sure what you're trying to test here, but if you want to create the file in case it doesn't exist, then you want to use `! -f $filename`. `-f` tests if a file exists, and `!` inverts the test.

Also note that in the assignment, the tilde isn't expanded, but left as-is, since it's within quotes:

```
template_file="~/mytest_template.c";
```

You're not using that variable in the subsequent redirection, or in the `cp` command, so you don't get issues from that.

So,

```
template=~/mytest_template.c
final=~/mytest.c
if [[ ! -f $template ]]; then
    echo "..." > "$template"
fi
cp "$template" "$final"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why are "$file"s in double quotes?

Comment: (By the way, It's just a script for my temporary tests while doing C. There is a function called "ctest" which can be called with one of the "create", "compile", "run", "clear" commands, e.g "ctest create", thanks once again).

Comment: @Moytaba, the quotes are necessary when the variables contain whitespace or wildcards (`*?[]`). That's not the case here, but it's still a good habit to get into quoting them. See, e.g. [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373) and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting